# Even Degree Polynomials limit to Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials

Let $p: R\rightarrow R$ be an even degree polynomial. Assume that $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$.

How do I go about using the fact that it is an even degree polynomial to prove this? It's easy enough to understand why this is true (because any negative number that has an even degree will be positive), but how do I actually go about proving this?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: First, prove it for even-degree polynomials with only one term - i.e., of the form $ax^{2n}$.

Then, suppose I have an arbitrary polynomial of even degree - $ax^{2n}+$[lower-degree stuff]. Can you show that the lower-degree terms do not affect the limit at infinity?